# Django inlineformset multiplication and addition of fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying hard but no solution for this problem. I am trying to use javascript (Jquery) for multiplying and adding fields in an inlineformset.
However it does not seem to work.

Please guide to any existing solution. I ma trying to get Quantity*price in Amount field.

[The form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTEEZ.jpg)

Jquery used for form:

```
<script type="text/C#" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".items input").keyup(multInputs);

    function multInputs() {
        var mult = 0;
        // for each row:
        $("tr.items").each(function () {
            // get the values from this row:
            var $val1 = $('.id_serviceitems1-0-Quantity', this).val();
            var $val2 = $('.id_serviceitems1-0-Rate', this).val();
            var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1);
            $('.id_serviceitems1-0-Amount',this).value($total);
        });

    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: jquery `$('#id_serviceitems1-0-Amount').val()` works as a getter and also as a setter. So instead of `$('.id_serviceitems1-0-Amount',this).value($total);`, use `$('.id_serviceitems1-0-Amount',this).val($total);`

Comment: @slackmart changed all . to # and value to val. It worked. Thank you

Comment: Still if someone can guide to a existing jquery package for it!!!

Comment: Glad to help you. To handle the inlineformsets, take a look at https://github.com/mbertheau/jquery.django-formset